# seeding default_random_engine?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++11, random

I'm using visual studio 2010 which doesn't support `<chrono>`, so I have to seed `default_random_engine`. Thus, I've decided to seed it with `rand` as following

```
srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
std::default_random_engine engine(rand());
std::normal_distribution<double> randn(0.0, 0.3);
```

instead of the following

```
unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
std::default_random_engine engine(seed);
std::normal_distribution<double> randn(0.0, 0.3);
```

I'm getting what I'm expecting to acquire for both methods. My question is are there any considerations should I pay attention to by using rand()? (Note: I have no choice to use `<chrono>`

Comment: You might want to read http://www.pcg-random.org/posts/cpp-seeding-surprises.html a blog about problems when seeding with to few numbers and/or seeding using the current time.

Comment: @KaspervandenBerg, amazing link. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I recommend grabbing a seed from [`std::random_device`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device):

```
std::default_random_engine engine(std::random_device{}());
```

which should provide you with significantly more entropy than `std::time`.

Answer (score 8):

According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/random_device/, they recommend that you don't use `std::random_device`, as it isn't portable:

> Notice that random devices may not always be available to produce
>   random numbers (and in some systems, they may even never be
>   available).

On a related page (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/linear_congruential_engine/linear_congruential_engine/), they give the following as an example of creating a seed:

```
unsigned seed1 = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
```

Comment: Both answers are correct, but this is safest. If attaining the maximum entropy possible in your PRNG is important, one could also check the entropy of random_device (std::random_device::entropy() returns 0 if a prng was used to generate seeds, and it is therefore not a good option) and if it is too low, then use the above time_since_epoch() call.