# Random generator for guess game

Tags: c++, random, generator

I've been searching for a better solution than my own and I haven't really been able to find one that I understand or that works for me.

I have made the simple game where the computer randomly generates a number which you then guess a number and if it is higher the computer says higher and so on..

The problem is my randomly generated number, after looking up alot of information regarding the `<random>`, `uniform_int_distribution` and `default_random_engine`. I have found out that the computer generates a random number, but **if you run the program again the same random number will be generated**.

My solution:

```
uniform_int_distribution<unsigned> u(0,100); // code to randomly generate numbers between 0 and 100
default_random_engine e; // code to randomly generate numbers

size_t userInput; // User input to find out where to look in the vector
vector<int> randomNumbers; //vector to hold the random numbers
unsigned start = 0, ending = 101, cnt = 0; // used in the game not important right now



cout << "Please enter a number between 1 and 1000 for randomness" << endl;

cin >> userInput;

for(size_t i = 0; i < 1000; ++i){ //for loop to push numbers into the vector
    randomNumbers.push_back(u(e));
}

unsigned guess = randomNumbers[userInput]; // finally the number that the user will have to guess in the game
```

My solution right now is to use a vector where I push alot of randomly generated numbers in then ask the user to type a number which then the computer uses for the game. But there should be a better way of doing this. And my question is therefore

### Is there a better way to randomly generate numbers to use in the game?

Comment: seems to be same subject than http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105867/seeding-default-random-engine. the answer suggest to set the seed using std::default_random_engine engine(std::random_device{}());

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either use `std::random_device` in place of `std::default_random_engine`, or else think of a way to provide a different number to the engine each time it is run.

This number is called a "seed" and can be passed as an optional parameter to the constructor. Since `std::default_random_engine` is implementation-specific, and different engines do different things about seeding, you generally want to choose a specific engine if you're providing a seed. A deterministic pseudo-random number generator will produce the same sequence of outputs for any given seed, so you want to use a different seed each time.

For no-security uses like a guessing game, the most "obvious" thing to use as a seed is the current time. Generally speaking this is different each time the program is run, although obviously if you can run the program twice in less than the granularity of the clock then that's not the case. So using the time to seed your random engine is pretty limited but will do the job for a toy program.

Comment: Oh, I tried to use random_device before but my program always crashed when trying to use it, guess I implemented it wrongly somehow. I did not either know that you could use the current time as a seed, I had tried using a seed with a constant number but with no success (of course) thank you for clearing it up!

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply:

```
#include <ctime> // for time()
#include <cstdlib> // for srand()

srand(time(NULL));    // Initializes the rand() function
int randomNumber = rand()%100;    // Random number between 0 and 99.
```

What this does is the `rand()` seed is set at the current time, meaning that every execution of the program will have a different seed for `rand()`.

Still just pseudo-random solution, though suitable for your purposes.

Comment: Thank you, I had tried to use srand before but did not know that you could use the time as a seed, tried it and it worked!

Comment: That's a classic :) It makes me remember the old RANDOMIZE TIMER

Comment: Because it is not uniform and the OP was asking the best solution. See: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful

Comment: @Csq: to be fair, anyone willing to use `default_random_engine` should probably be equally willing to use `rand()`, since they're allowed to be the same non-uniform cheap and cheerful RNG. But yes, the quality of `rand()` is always an issue.

Comment: @SteveJessop There's also the `%` issue, which doesn't help (and should be avoided by using the `uniform_int_distribution`.)

Answer (score 1):

That's because your random number is actually what we call a [pseudorandom number generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator)

It's just a machine that given a starting number generates a large list of seemingly random numbers. As you don't provide a starting number, the generated list of random numbers is thus always the same. One easy way to fix this is to use the current time as a starting value or 'seed', which is an argument of the constructor of `std::default_random_engine`.

You can also use your machines real random number generator `std::random_device` as a replacement for `std::default_random_engine`